# hp probook 6570b flashing capslock

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, hp-laptop

I have a hp probook 6570b that I am trying to fix for a friend. When you turn it on the first thing it doses, is that the caps lock and scroll lock key flashes once and after that only the caps lock key is constantly flashing, it never boots up and you can't get in to the bios, I have cheked the ram, remounted the cpu, Change the battery. What should I do?

Comment: [HP Notebook PCs - Computer Does Not Start and Emits an LED or Beep Code](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01732674#AbT2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an HP laptop, the Caps Lock and Scroll Lock keys are used to diagnose hardware failures and startup issues. 
The number of flashes and on what key is used to diagnose the issue.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/En4v3]

A quick Google search would yield this: http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01732674
 which explaines this in more detail

Comment: I already knew about that page on hp's website, but it dosen't say anything about **CAPS LOCK** blinking **continuously**

Comment: @Linushg111 Get the maintenance manual for laptop, it will give more model specific information. https://goo.gl/V4V0Bc It is expected of Superuser users to take on some​ responsibility and do their own research before asking a question, saying you were aware of this page could have sped up this process.